# What routes to add in routes.rb for a controller create function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, controllers

My chap_three_controller.rb file :

```
class ChapThreeController < ApplicationController
   def create
      @marker = Marker.new(params[:m])
      if @marker.save
         res={:success=>true,:content=>"<div><strong>found </strong>#{marker.found}
              </div><div><strong>left </strong>#{marker.left}</div>"}
      else
         res={:success=>false,:content=>"Could not save the marker"}
      end
      render :text=>res.to_json
   end
end
```

My routes.rb file

```
match '/map3', :to => 'chap_three#map'
match '/map3/create', :to => 'chap_three#:action'
```

Am I doing it right matching the create function in the controller to my routes? Because it isn't working..

This is a snippet of my javascript code:

```
request.open('GET', 'create' + getVars, true);
 request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
 //the request is complete
    var success=false;
    var content='Error contacting web service';
    try {
 //parse the result to JSON (simply by eval-ing it)
      res=eval( "(" + request.responseText + ")" );
      content=res.content;
      success=res.success;
    }catch (e){
       success=false;
     }
```

The error I keep getting is 'Error contacting web service'. This means that my request.responseText isn't working and the create method in my controller isn't doing anything....Any help would be great

Answer (score 0):

You want your match to be:

```
match '/map3/create' => 'chap_three#create'
```

The `#` separates controller name and action name respectively and the `:to` is unnecessary and only used when defining a `root` route. I recommend reading up on the [Rails Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: Trying to store params[:m] to database through  @marker = Marker.new(params[:m])... but its not working..is it a mass assignment problem? cant figure it out

Comment: That's fine, any query parameters you add to the URL will be available in `params`. So if you're URL was `/map3/create?m[left]=some_value&m[found]=true` then `params[:m]` would have values for `left` and `found`.

Comment: It could be a mass assignment problem. Make sure you have `attr_accessible` for the values you are sending. You can also check if `@marker.save` is returning `false` and if so, check `@marker.errors` to see why it's failing. You can also switch it over to `@marker.save!` which will throw an exception and might make it more obvious during your debugging.

Comment: I checked the server output and the values are according to what you have said and m holds all values as a hash.... but it isn't getting stored in the database Marker... Any idea why that could be happening? It shows Active_Record:0.0ms